# While trying to run my app I m getting this error below

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

So what happened was the I completed my layout and thought to try on my phone and this happened :-

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources
>   C:\Users\Jit.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.4-all\9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1\gradle-4.4-all\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar\1c402682e6b4dfb78349fd8b5c0ad010\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
>   Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

  > - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  >     BUILD FAILED in 59s
  >     9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date}

Comment: The error log is telling you exactly what happened. Post your app-level `build.gradle` file and tell us your device's Android version so we can try and tell you how to fix it.

Comment: My device is Xiaomi Redmi 3sp with android marshmallow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in AAPT2 on Windows - AAPT2 had trouble handing non-ascii characters as well as paths longer than 240 characters. Here it looks like you hit the second case - the path is 249 characters and that's why AAPT2 can't find it.

Update your version of the android gradle plugin to 3.2.0-alpha11 or newer where this issue is already fixed. Update your app's project level **build.gradle** file:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'
```

Comment: I got this issue again!!!( This time the android.tools.build:gradle is version 3.2.0 alpha12)

Comment: I got this error again but this time the android tool build gradle thing is of version 3.2.0 alpha 12

Comment: So it works with alpha11 but doesn't with alpha12? That sounds suspicious